# My Ec2 Host Down: Unhealthy for 1 hour and can't load the site in the instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

My host is unhealthy for 1 hour and when I access my site using the instance public IP (not ELB DNS), the page loads infinite and nothing happen.
I can't access the server via SSH because not connect.
I tried everything suggested on forums and articles and nothing works.

My last nginx access log:

```
172.31.47.107 - - [07/Jul/2017:21:48:19 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
172.31.25.106 - - [07/Jul/2017:21:48:20 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
172.31.47.107 - - [07/Jul/2017:21:50:49 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
172.31.25.106 - - [07/Jul/2017:21:50:49 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
172.31.47.107 - - [07/Jul/2017:21:51:05 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 54 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
172.31.25.106 - - [07/Jul/2017:21:51:13 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 54 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
```

My health check config:

- Response Timeout: 5
- Interval: 30
- Unhealthy threshold: 2
- Healthy threshold: 10

More ELB info:

- Idle timeout: 600 (was 60)
- The maximum latency before down: 4616

When I access the site (Load Balancer), I got the error: HTTP ERROR 503

I rebooted the instance 3 times.

System Information: Linux with Nginx and Passenger

I apreciate any information.
Thanks!

Comment: A reboot only *requests* the instance reboot itself.  If it is unhealthy, it will not see or be able to act on the reboot request.  Stop it, wait for it to stop, then start it.  This is equivalent to the power switch, but before it comes back up, it will be migrated to new physical hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't ssh to this ec2 instance, it appears the instance if failing reachability check. Click on the instance `status checks` tab and ensure the instance passes both instance and system status check. If it doesn't then `stop` the instance (not reboot) and `start` it up again. This will migrate your ec2 instance to a healthy host

Comment: Hey, thanks the answer. Do you know it there are some lost data? Or if I have to start manually the services, like nginx, passenger, postgres etc?

Comment: Hello, there is would be no data lost as long as you are running EBS volume and not instance store. You don't need to restart any of the services you mentioned above as long as you have set them to start up on restarted for runlevel 3 if not you will need to restart them.

Comment: I did not configure the server. Do you know how I can find out if the services are configured to start automatically?

Comment: use `chkconfig --list` you will see services and associated runlevels they can startup in automatically. You can see how to enable your services here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/chkconfig-examples/